# WPF DataGrid: LostKeyboardFocus vs. IsEditing and AddRows

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, datagrid, lost-focus

I have a WPF `DataGrid` with a single `DataGridTextColumn`.
It lets the user enter a variable number of dates (the dates themselves are wrapped in a class, for binding purposes).

But (using `UpdateSourceTrigger=Default`) when the user uses the Tab key to navigate away from the `DataGrid`, the **cell he was editing doesn't seem to leave editing mode** / get validated.
The entered value is shown in red, and the row header shows an exclamation mark that is framed by a dotted line.

Setting `UpdateSourceTrigger` to `LostFocus` fixes that - but when my code resets the underlying collection (to facilitate consecutive user input) to a single-item collection, the `DataGrid` only shows a single row. Despite `CanUserAddRows="True"` the new, **empty row goes missing** (if my code resets the collection by simply clearing it, only the column header is shown).

I tried to work around that by setting `Mode` to `OneWayToSource` - but then the `DataGrid` no longer shows the entered values.

If I set `UpdateSourceTrigger` to `PropertyChanged`, the **validation happens to soon**, resulting in a bad user experience (Dates should be formatted DD/MM/YYYY. But, as soon as the user enters "1/1", "01/01/2016" is shown. Using backspace to edit the year, causes the value to change to "01/01/0201", and so on)

**There seems to be a solution** (https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/983b3b5b-7115-4821-b621-85b43578636e/how-can-i-end-a-datagrid-cell-edit-when-focus-switches-to-a-winforms-hosted-control?forum=wpf) **that requires code-behind**, but I'd much prefer a cleaner solution.

My code:

```
<DataGrid AutoGenerateColumns="False"CanUserAddRows="True" ItemsSource="{Binding CourseDatesParameterForRequest}">
<DataGrid.Columns>
    <DataGridTextColumn Header="Datum" Binding="{Binding Date, ConverterCulture=nl-BE, Mode=TwoWay, 
        StringFormat=\{0:dd/MM/yyyy\},  UpdateSourceTrigger=Default, ValidatesOnDataErrors=True}">
    </DataGridTextColumn>
</DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>
```

---

```
private ObservableCollection<DateWrapper> _courseDatesParameterForRequest;
public ObservableCollection<DateWrapper> CourseDatesParameterForRequest
{
    get { return _courseDatesParameterForRequest; }
    set
    {
        if (value != _courseDatesParameterForRequest)
        {
            _courseDatesParameterForRequest = value;

            if (PropertyChanged != null)
            {
                PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(nameof(CourseDatesParameterForRequest)));
            }
        }
    }
}
```

---

```
   public class DateWrapper
    {
        public int ID { get; set; }
        public DateTime Date { get; set; }
        public DateWrapper(DateTime date)
        {
            Date = date;
        }
        public DateWrapper(){}
    }
```

Thanks in advance!